# Page break differences between biblatex 2.9a and 3.4?

Tags: biblatex

On a whim I decided to try out biblatex 3.4 on my 784 page book, which had been originally set with TexLive 2014 and biblatex 2.9a .  When I ran TL 2014 with BL 3.4 dev, I found a difference in page breaks in my bibliography.  Formerly on one page the last few entries were 'N' entries, two 'O' entries, and one 'P' entry.  Now the page breaks between the 'O' and 'P' entries.  So I speculated that perhaps something connected with the semantics of `\bibparsep` had changed, even if the numerical value of `\bibparsep` had not changed in the last 2 years.

So the question is, what can possibly have changed in the mean time?

I realize this is a vague question, whose answer will be technical and ultimately philosophically uninteresting.  I have reproduced something like this behavior with this.  It uses the examples file in the biblatex documentation.

```
\documentclass[      10pt]{book}

\RequirePackage[ language=autobib, maxitems=4, maxnames=4, backend=biber, style=authortitle]{biblatex}[2010/03/19]

\setlength{\bibinitsep}{.5\baselineskip}

% http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib
% MD5 (biblatex-examples.bib) = 0118071a5ed11ce3357cc8cea139e407

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a question is senseless. You can see what has changed, but ask us to guess.

Comment: `biblatex` has got a huge update in version 3.3, so difference in pagebreaks are quite like compared to version 2.9a. On the other hand, version 3.4 still is in evelopment, which is another variable in your equation of miracles.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion what to do with this question?  Ulrike is right when she says that *you* can see what changed, while we have no way of knowing what changed for you and so can only guess.

Comment: @Johannes_B: All the differences between 2.9a and 3.4 that I can see in the documentation seem to have to do with database internals and tweaking multilingual support and so on, not at all likely to affect page breaking.  Oh, and by the way, I did not originally compare 3.3 vs 2.9a because of the microtype bug, fixed in 3.4.  But my revised example does not use microtype, so I can test 3.3 with it.  Page breaks differ with 2.9a and 3.3, when used with TL 2014.  So one variable of my equation of miracles can be eliminated.

Comment: @moewe:  I dunno: forget such a senseless question, perhaps?

Comment: Presumably a bug was fixed between 2.9a and 3.3 which prevented `\bibinitsep` from actually doing anything? If I run your example with binaries etc. from 2014, that setting appears to do nothing. If I run it with current TeX Live, it does just what it says on the tin. Of course, this is going to affect the page breaks. That's expected. If you want to emulate the old behaviour, just don't use non-zero `\bibinitsep`.

Comment: @cfr I think we've got a winner there (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/265) would you mind turning your comment into an answer?

Comment: @moewe Done - though you did the bug-report finding ;). I just guessed *a priori*.

Answer (score 3):

If I compile your code with TeX Live 2014 and compare with results using the current TeX Live 2015, I can reproduce the issue.

The difference in page-breaking is the result of a bug which affected the 2014 version of Biblatex when using Biber as the backend but which is fixed in the version currently included in TeX Live 2015.

I inferred the existence of this bug and the fix, but [moewe actually did the detective work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308529/page-break-differences-between-biblatex-2-9a-and-3-4?noredirect=1#comment752473_308529) to find the [bug report](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/265).

With the 2014 versions, setting `\bibinitsep` to a non-zero value has no effect when using Biber.

With the 2015 versions, `\bibinitsep` does what it says on the tin i.e. when set to a non-zero dimension, it inserts vertical space between sets of entries in the bibliography, grouping the entries according to the first author's first initial.

- So, for example, the first group might include **A**quinas, **A**nselm and **A**ristotle, while the second might include **B**acon, **B**erkeley and **B**radley and the specified spacing would be inserted between the last entry in the first group (Aristotle) and the first entry in the second (Bacon).

One effect of this bug being fixed is, therefore, that page breaks will change due to the insertion of vertical space. To emulate the 2014 behaviour, ensure that `\bibinitsep` is set to its default zero value.